# Sections of the sum of two copies of the tangent bundle of the $2$-sphere

Tags: vector-bundles

If $T$ is the tangent bundle of $S^2$, then $T\oplus T$ is trivial of rank $4$. Indeed, $T\oplus\mathbb R=\mathbb R^3$, so $T\oplus T\oplus\mathbb R^2=\mathbb R^6$ and $T\oplus T$ is stably trivial: since its rank is larger than the dimension of the base $S^2$, it is in fact trivial.

It follows that while $T$ has no nowhere-zero sections, $T\oplus T$ has four.

> Is there a natural way to write them down?

Comment: I randomly stumbled upon this question, and I feel like I don't understand what you are asking: what do you mean $T\oplus T$ has four nowhere-zero sections? Shouldn't it be continuum many nowhere-zero sections? And to construct one is quite easy: let first subsection be along the meridians from the south to the north pole, having two zeroes, and the second subsection from the east to west pole (choose any two other points on the sphere as east and west poles).

Comment: Things get much more apparent once you already write the comment... Do you by any chance want four *everywhere linearly independent* sections?